# Getting Syntaxerror : invalid syntax with print

Tags: printing, syntax-error, python-3.6

Testing out first time in Idle

```
def string_length(str1):
    count = 0
    for char in str1:
        count += 1
    return count
print(string_length("books"))
```

keep getting Syntaxerror : invalid syntax. I saw that print needs print () with python 3, i have already done. Not sure is it that i did not install Idle correctly

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating a function to count the number of characters, why don't you use the defined function. like

```
print(len("book"))
```

it gives the output as 4.

Comment: actually i was trying out Idle for one of the w3 exercises i am picking up. and yes, i can use print(len("")) but not sure where it went wrong there

Comment: Ok, i just found out, i was using the python Idle shell the whole time, and not the Idle. Silly me. But for all beginners out there like me, you may want to check the part on saving the file to run separately, and not just run from the shell